# Angular get Session ID the same for all API calls

Tags: angular, api, session

I have an Angular front-end and Spring Boot Backend application
Right now, my application is producing different SessionIDs for each API call. I am trying to get the same SessionId for all API calls. I've been trying to access the 'Set-Cookie' header to get the JSESSIONID and set it to the other API calls, however, I'm unable to do that. Is it possible to set the JSESSIONID the same as in the 'Set-Cookie' header for API? Or do I need to use other methods? Any help is appretiated.

Answer (score 0):

you should send your requests with `{withCredentials: true}`. in this way cookies are being set for  the domain of your api server, as well as they are being sent with the request.

example code:

```
http.get<Data>('my-data-url', {withCredentials: true});
```

or inside of interceptor, if you want to do it for all of your http requests

```
intercept(req, next) {
  return next.handle(req.clone({withCredentials: true}));
}
```

there is a more popular way to identify user: add a bearer token to headers of every request, but that would require a more complex configuration or even implementation on the backend side.

Comment: I've actually tried that before and didn't get much change. I still have the JSESSIONIDs different from the api calls.

Comment: the only option that I can propose is to debug cookies that are being sent with your requests